# Can't ajax reload without page reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want it to only "reload" into the `#searchuserc`. I have searched so much information but I can't solve the problem.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#onlineusers").load("online.php");
    $("#searchuserc").show();
    setInterval(function() {
      $("#onlineusers").load("online.php");
    }, 5000);
    $(".search").click(function() {
      $("#onlineusers").hide();
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission
      $.ajax({
          url: 'searchuser.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: $(this).serialize(), // it will serialize the form data
          dataType: 'html'
        })
        .done(function(data) {
          $('#searchuserc').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('#searchuserc').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
          });
        })
        .fail(function() {
          alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');
        });
    });
  });
```

this is my HTML file

```html
 <form method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="searchuser" name="searchuser" placeholder="Sök efter en användare..." />
  <input type="submit" class="search" name="searchbtn" value="Sök" />
</form>
<div id="searchuserc">
</div>
```

Comment: You call e.preventDefault() but don't define e, check your js console for errors, I think you need $(".search").click(function(e){

Comment: `$(this).serialize()` - the clicked button?

Comment: perhaps change `$('#searchuserc').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('#searchuserc').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
          });` to `$('#searchuserc').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).html(data);
          }).fadeIn('slow');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$(".search").click(function() {
  ...
```

use

```
$(".search").closest("form").submit(function(e) {
  ...
```

Code inside the handler can stay the same.